# Firebug hits my debugger statement. What does 'continue' do and what does 'disable' do?

Tags: javascript, firebug

If I hit continue, does the code execute normally after the debugger statement?
If I hit disable, the debugger statement vanishes. But how does the code execute? Does it do nothing? Does it execute normally after the debugger statement? Or does it start from the beginning (i.e., refresh)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Clicking "Continue" resumes normal execution after the `debugger` statement.  Clicking "Disable" *both* resumes normal execution **and** disables the break point, so that the next time that block of code is executed, the `debugger` statement is ignored.

In other words, "Disable" is the same as "Continue", but prevents you from being prompted next time.